# Convert database int to string

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have "codes" on database that act as **int type** and i wanted to connect it to my program on c#, so those int type will act like string type, and the computer recognized it too.

The following code is the example of my program that i already tried and it works perfectly, the int type act as string type and when i run the program, and hit "1" on the keyboard, the autocomplete show the number "10" below the textbox that i hit "1" before:

```
int num = 10;

while(dReader.Read())
{
  codesCollections.Add(Convert.ToString(num)); // AutoStringCompleteCollection
}
```

My questions is, how do i connect the codes(name of the column in my database) "int type" to the program? so the computer will recognized it as string?
So, whenever i hit the "0" on the textbox, the autocomplete will come out and show the number that starts with "0", based on my database

i already tried the following code, but not works:

```
while(dReader.Read())
{
  codesCollections.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code")));
}
```

The code after GetOrdinal is refer to the column of "Code" in my database which filled by int value.

In the first code, we defined the value of int type on our code, in the second code, i tried to connect to the database, because the value of int type is all on the database, but failed.

Comment: You really need to put something relevant as the title...

Comment: Please modify your question title to actually describe your problem. "Please help, urgent!" is _completely_ useless.

Comment: Guys, it would have been more constructive to simply edit the title.

Comment: for the second code, the autocomplete does not show the number that starts based on what the users type (like on google), but the first code is working, because we defined the value inside of code, not database

Comment: @zmbq I thought about editing it, but I honestly can't understand what OP is trying to do or what the problem is and wouldn't even know what to put.

Comment: So it looks like a problem with GetOrdinal, not the conversion.

Comment: @Michelle: do you want me to put the full code? or what?

Comment: @Jim: i already tried:

codesCollection.Add(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code"))

and the error says "cannot convert from "int" to "string", and the best overloaded for the AutoCompleteStringCollection.Add(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't work.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
codesCollections.Add(dReader.GetString(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code")));
```

Maybe this would work.  Maybe this?

Comment: does not work either, the error says AutoStringCompleteCollection.Add(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: does not work either, the program runs perfectly, but it cannot connect to the database

Comment: So it's a database problem?  Well, maybe some progress.  Can you connect with it with other routines?